# Is there any Facebook event API?

Tags: facebook

Is there any paid or free event API? I would like to get event data based on location and date ranges parameters. Do you know anything that provides that functionality?

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/).

Comment: I think it only returns single event. As I mentioned, I need to get all events based on location and date range. For example: "Barcelona", 01-01-2020, 05-01-2020